# How to refresh a page in Maximo through an automation script

Tags: automation, maximo

I am trying to refresh my Work Order from an automation script. Does anyone know a refresh function, or if there is no refresh function is there a way to navigate back to the same Work Order from the automation script, which should result in it refreshing.

Comment: Is this related to your previous question? Because this is the kind of problem that can occur when you explicitly call `save`.

Comment: ..when you explicitly call `save()` on an MboSet that *you* did not get for yourself from MXServer. When you do get an MboSet from MXServer, you must always `close()` it and you must `save()` it if you want it saved.

Comment: @Preacher Thanks for translating my implied chain of thought :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot explicitly refresh UI from script, However if you this script attached to a button on the main mbo ( WORKORDER in this case) or it is linked to action in action menu. the system automatically refresh the UI.
Also in case of attribute launchpoint , this is done by default. 
So if you may give more about your business need, maybe we can find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As of Maximo version 7.6.0.9, Try to check if the record is saved then call mbo.getThisMboSet().reset() before your action and see if that refreshes it. Another way is to set a field that has a changeaction on the xml of the application designer to refresh/reset a table. Newer versions of Maximo may have needed features.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Comment: @Machavity: The question was tagged [tag:maximo], which is a specific product from IBM. If Amer had suggested buying "Amer Software's Fancy Solution", I could agree with your comment. However, Amer merely presented upgrading the product in OP's question as one option for overcoming the OP's perceived problem. It's like OP had trouble with his Linux app and Amer said OP could try upgrading Linux. If you still really have a problem with this Answer, then perhaps the whole [tag:maximo] tag should be removed (to its own SE site?) and its followers should leave SO.

Comment: @Preacher Check out Revision 2. My comment does not apply to the original post, but there have been other attempts to promote that domain

Comment: @Machavity Thank you for the clarification, for taking out the spam, and for the kind help provided to Amer to help him do things right from now on. Should I need to do clean-up like you have done, I will learn from this to note in my comment that I have edited out the self-promotion, for the sake of others to whom it might not be obvious.